# How to delete components from DOM react if it is placed inside BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two pages: first with layout, second without layout. First contains `Routes` for navigate on my site, second contains `Routes` for login, sign-in and 404.
Tag `BrowserRouter` contains these pages.
So if I click some `Route` from page with layout, page without layout contains page 404 or if I click some `Route` from page without layout component AsideMenu does not fade from DOM.

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <LayoutPages>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
            <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductItem />} />
            <Route path="/contacts" element={<Contacts />} />
            <Route path="/cabinet" element={<Cabinet />} />
            <Route path="/cars" element={<Cars />} />
            <Route path="/products/:productId/review/:reviewId" element={<Review />} />
            <Route path="/todo" element={<ToDo />} />
            <Route path="/forms" element={<Forms />} />
          </Routes>
        </LayoutPages>
        <LayoutEmpty>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/log-in" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Registration />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound404 />} />
          </Routes>
        </LayoutEmpty>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div >
  );
}
```

LayoutPages.js

```
import React from "react";
import AsideMenu from "../AsideMenu/AsideMenu";

function LayoutPages(props) {
  return (
    <div className="LayoutPages">
      <AsideMenu />
      <div className="container">
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LayoutPages;
```

LayoutEmpty.js

```
import React from "react";

function LayoutEmpty(props) {
  return (
    <div className="LayoutEmpty">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default LayoutEmpty;
```

If some Route from `<LayoutPages>` was clicked content in `<LayoutEmpty>` must be cleaned or vice versa if some Route from `<LayoutEmpty>` was clicked content in `<LayoutPages>` must be cleaned.
It is partly work but component `<AsideMenu />` is always  in the DOM and page 404 too.

How can I fix it?